# How do I reset my search result link?

Tags: 8, search, plugins

I created a custom search plugin for a custom entity. I would like to change the link that is presented to the user on the list of results. I had originally set it to the canonical page using $entity->url(‘canonical’), but now I want to use Url::fromRoute(), to a custom controller.

I made the appropriate changes to the plugin class, cleared cache and ran cron a few times and the search results still point to the admin canonical page. Is there something else I need to do to push the change through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited some more, cleared cache and ran cron again and it worked.